unity animator force parent state to do transition
I may have designed it wrong, but I want to achieve the following effect:
No matter how many sub-state machines there are, they will switch immediately as long as I trigger LocomotionToActiveMotion.
I am in locomotion > idle, i trigged LocomotionToActiveMotion, it still looping idle and the trigged stay actived.
In fact, I just don’t want to setup transitions from every state in Locomotion to to every state in ActiveMotion. Because theoretically every motion of Locomotion can be connected to an attack and every attack/dodge have transitions to idle obviously. And I struggled a lot with the heavy repeated work and clean visual. Please tell me if there is any better approach.
here is my animator:



